# How to upgrade salt-minion service on Windows Servers from Salt-master without getting an error

Tags: upgrade, salt-stack

So I've a single master which have around 300+ minions connected to it. With the latest upgrade 3004.1; I want to upgrade all of them. They are a mixture of Linux and Windows servers.
I'm able to upgrade the Linux servers flawlessly from the salt-master using a state file as suggested by the FAQ section documentation of Salt which can be found [here](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/faq.html#upgrade-without-automatic-restart)

However, when I'm trying to do the same thing for Windows, the upgrade happens in the background without any issues but I get an error as **Minion did not return. [No Response].** Below is the code which is installing the latest package on the Windows Minion.:

```
Upgrade Salt Minion:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: salt-minion
    - version: 3004.1
    - order: last

Enable Salt Minion:
  service.enabled:
    - name: salt-minion
    - require:
      - pkg: Upgrade Salt Minion

Restart Salt Minion:
  cmd.run:
{%- if grains['kernel'] == 'Windows' %}
    - name: 'C:\salt\salt-call.bat service.restart salt-minion'
{%- else %}
    - name: 'salt-call service.restart salt-minion'
{%- endif %}
    - bg: True
    - onchanges:
      - pkg: Upgrade Salt Minion
```

As we can see above, it's a fairly simple state file to install the minion service. I was thinking if there's anyway wherein we can put an explicit sleep in the install command so that when the response is returned, I can see Green output with proper results.

*Note: I can still re-run the state file again and it will give me the proper result on the second time as it will skip the ones that's already upgraded. But I think there should be a more correct way of doing this via Salt.*

Anyone else have upgraded their Windows minions via Master. Please share your thoughts.

---

2nd Qts: Since this is kinda related so asking it here if anyone else have found a solution? I'm unable to install the latest Salt package on Windows Server 2008? Has anyone else faced a similar problem? I know the server is quite and at EOL but for some unavoidable circumstances it will take time for the upgrade to happen. Suggestions on this please:

[image]

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/57686) on a similar topic might be helpful.

Comment: @seshadri_c Thanks for the article. However, my question isn't answered there. I've still asked my question again there in short. Hoping for an answer from that portal.

Comment: I installed Salt 3004.1-1 on Windows 2008 SP2 without any issues. But more recent versions of Salt don't want to start.